# PHP MYSQL opposite of 'AND' clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, conditional-statements

I'm trying to return information from a MYSQL database using PHP with the following conditions:

```
mysql_query("SELECT name.name, type.type FROM style, name, type WHERE style.name=name.id AND style.type=type.id AND (style.model IS NULL *OR* style.make IS NULL)");
```

Is there a way to specify one of two conditions to be true, like an OR statement rather than AND?

Comment: What you have is good (except for the *). What's not working?

Comment: yep - take out the * and just say OR

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  I was looking for the answer without trying that first, and I couldn't find anything on the OR clause so I figured it didn't exist.  It's working perfectly now, thanks.

Comment: haha! Probably because OR is such a common word, it may be ignored by search engines. This made me laugh a bit though.

Comment: @Evert: worse, "OR" is an operator on some search engines. They don't ignore it, they use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look here: [MySQL Reference for logical operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html)

What you looking for will be `OR` or `XOR`.